# CMake: How to prevent 'target_link_libraries' from adding visual studio project reference to a static library?

Tags: cmake, linker, include, include-path

I just started participating in my first cmake project. The project that has many **static libraries** and a single executable that link them all.

Currently, a typical CMakeLists.txt for one of the static libraries 'this_lib' has this form:

```
target_include_directories(
    this_lib
    PUBLIC
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries (this_lib PUBLIC
    lib1
    lib2
    lib3
    lib4
    lib5
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

`target_link_libraries` adds additional include directories **and** project dependencies in the form of a visual studio **ProjectReference** entry in the generated vcxproj file. As a result, the 'this_lib' is not compiled concurrently with the rest of the libraries which greatly increases compile time.

So is there a way to configure `target_link_libraries`  so it will not add a Project Reference in Visual Studio?

This is what I tried so far:

If I move the parameters from `target_link_libraries` to `target_include_directories`, I get compilation errors (missing include) because it seems `target_link_libraries` operates recursively, meaning it adds include directories of linked libraries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20233).

A quick fix for this problem is to use [OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES.html) properties that was introduced in version 3.19.

> When this property is set to true, some dependencies for a static or object library may be removed at generation time if they are not necessary to build the library, since static and object libraries don't actually link against anything.

The documentation is unclear as to how this property is actually set.
But I managed to get it working using `set_target_properties`:

```
add_library(this_lib STATIC ...)

set_target_properties(this_lib PROPERTIES OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES ON ...)
```

Or alternatively for all projects at the top level CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES 1)
```

I can clearly see that most of the dependencies are removed.